# Spring hateoas how to set relationship and have array for single link also

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

Can someone please let me know how to get below response using hateoas

```
{
    "ticketID" : 345,
    "links": [ {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "rest/INL_TM/rest/v1/ticket/345"
    } ]
}
```

But I am getting response as

```
{
    "ticketID" : 345,
    "links":  {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "rest/INL_TM/rest/v1/ticket/345"
    }
}
```

Also how do I set rel to custom value? I want something like rel = "getTicket"

Greeting.java

```
public class Greeting extends ResourceSupport {

    private final String content;

    @JsonCreator
    public Greeting(@JsonProperty("content") String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

GreetingController.java

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String TEMPLATE = "Hello, %s!";

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    @ResponseBody
    public HttpEntity<Greeting> greeting(
            @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {

        Greeting greeting = new Greeting(String.format(TEMPLATE, name));
        greeting.add(linkTo(methodOn(GreetingController.class).greeting(name)).withSelfRel());

        return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(greeting, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For the second question. Custom Rels. You add a link in your controller "withSelfRel()" if you use withRel("SomeString") then the rel will be SomeString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extend ResourceSupport in model class.
Return Resource instead of ResponseEntity

GreetingController.java

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {       

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
@ResponseBody
public Resource<Greeting> greeting(
@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {

Resource<Greeting> resourceResponse = new Resource<Greeting>("Some String");
resourceResponse.add(linkTo(methodOn(GreetingController.class).greeting("Some String")).withSelfRel());
return resourceResponse;
   }
}
```

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
   <version>0.16.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```